# select all the options using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a option list, I wanted to implement the select all feature of it. All I want to do is, if the parent option(Option Pa1) is call all the option element which is in the same class(11) should be selected. how can I do this  in jQuery ?

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="section_1" class="section_1">
    <option value="1" class="11 parent">Option Pa1</option>
    <option value="2"  class="11">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3" class="11">Option 3</option>
    <option value="11" class="11">Option 1</option>
    <option value="22" class="22 parent">Option Pa2</option>
    <option value="33" class="22">Option 3</option>
    <option value="44" class="22">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This kind of UI design is better suited to checkboxes. Clicking one `option` which then selects others is very unintuitive.

Comment: agree but I need a drop down list and the design won't match in the other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen for a click on any options with the class `.parent`.

Then it's a case of change the `select` property on the element clicked and every element *until* the next option with `.parent`. You can use [`.nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/) to extend your selection and [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to change the property:

```
$('select .parent').on('click', function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('.parent').prop('selected', true);
});
```

```js
$('select .parent').on('click', function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('.parent').prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="section_1" class="section_1" multiple>
    <option value="1" class="11 parent">Option Pa1</option>
    <option value="2"  class="11">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3" class="11">Option 3</option>
    <option value="11" class="11">Option 1</option>
    <option value="22" class="22 parent">Option Pa2</option>
    <option value="33" class="22">Option 3</option>
    <option value="44" class="22">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Please acknowledge the comment [written by Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840297/select-all-the-options-using-jquery#comment42245262_26840297) - End users usually expect only one option to be selected when it is clicked, especially since there is no immediate indication than some options are 'parents' of others. In his words; *This kind of UI design is better suited to checkboxes*:

```js
$('ul input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('li').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input type='checkbox'>Option Pa1
    <ul>
      <li><input type='checkbox'>Option 2</li>
      <li><input type='checkbox'>Option 3</li>
      <li><input type='checkbox'>Option 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><input type='checkbox'>Option Pa2
    <ul>
      <li><input type='checkbox'>Option 3</li>
      <li><input type='checkbox'>Option 4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @user1269524 How does what work, specifically? I've included links to documentation for both methods used.

Comment: this will break if I chose the second parent option first and select first

Comment: Please see [modifications by @A.Wolff](http://jsfiddle.net/0ueo0ycz/2/) above your comment.

Answer (score 0):

When a parent option is [clicked](http://api.jquery.com/click), select all options with the same class and mark them as selected using [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop). Note: I am assuming here that the parent elements here have only two classes "parent", and then the one they share with the child options. If that's not the case, you'll have to define a consistent grouping attribute using the HTML5 `data-*` attribute convention.

See runnable example below.

```js
$(function() {
  $("select .parent").click(function() {
    var classNm = this.className.replace("parent", "").trim();
    $("option." + classNm).prop("selected", true);
  });
});
```

```css
select {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" name="section_1" class="section_1">
  <option value="1" class="11 parent">Option Pa1</option>
  <option value="2" class="11">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3" class="11">Option 3</option>
  <option value="11" class="11">Option 1</option>
    <option value="99" >Random Value In the Middle</option>
    <option value="11" class="11">Option 5</option>
  <option value="22" class="22 parent">Option Pa2</option>
  <option value="33" class="22">Option 3</option>
  <option value="44" class="22">Option 4</option>
</select>
```